# Show that the set of vectors defined as directed line segments does not form a group...

Tags: vectors, group-actions

Show that the set of vectors defined as directed line segments does not form a group (1) with respect to scalar product (2) with respect to vector product.

Comment: Can you give the definition of a group ?

Comment: In mathematics, a group is an algebraic structure consisting of a set of elements together with an operation that combines any two elements to form a third element. The operation satisfies four conditions called the group axioms, namely closure, associativity, identity and invertibility.

Comment: Then, do the scalar and vector product satisfy closure ?

Comment: I do not considered it please explain

Comment: Do you understand the definition ?

Comment: Yes i understand

Comment: Please tell me how satisfied scalar and vector in closure

Comment: No, dot products of vector is not a binary composition, so it can't be a group. Vector cross product is not associative so it is not a group.

Answer (score 2):

Hint in both cases: directly check the four defining properties of a group operation until you hit one that is violated.

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: The usual definition of a group describes four properties; do you know what they are?

Comment: Yes i know but i want to know associativity property in this case.

Comment: OK here is my second hint: you do not need to check associativity in either case.

Comment: No i do not know

Comment: @Justpassingby +1 For trying to lead the OPer to the answer and not just giving it

Comment: How we can solve of both case by only closure property

Comment: The closure property answers the first case only: the scalar product of two vectors is no longer a vector. For the second case you need to look at other properties because closure is at least satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the vectors are in $V=\mathbb{R}^3$.

1) The dot product is an operation that take two vectors and gives a scalar as a result so $V$ cannot be a group with respect such operation because the result is not in $V$.

2) the cross product gives a vector as a result, but it's not associative (see [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity)) as required by the [axioms of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition).

Comment: I do not considered for vector